# re rendering and binding composable UI after save

Tags: jquery, razor, knockout.js, single-page-application

For the sake of simplicity, imagine building a flowchart designer. The markup/template representing each of the shape is rendered on the index page (cshtml templates generating knockout templates). User drags drops the shapes to create flowchart. Saves the flowchart. Now I would like to re render the flowchart and bind it to the model data that was saved. Some pseudo code

```
<script name="rectangle" type="text/html">
<input id="rectangle_t" type="text" data-bind="value:rectangle_name"></text>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function RectangleViewModel(){
    // instances of this model gets saved when a flowchart containing 
    // a rectangle is saved
     return {
        "rectangle_name" : ko.observable()  
    };
   }
</script>
```

Question :
How can I re-render the flow chart once saved in the backend? I would get a json and templates delivered from the server and i would like to rebuild the UI representation of the json. Flow is something like, build flowchart.. build a tree like json data representing a flowchart, save, rebuild flowchart.

Constraints :

1. the templates or catalog of templates has to come from the server because more templates will be added down the line. (lets say this is a business decision)
2. I can control what markup the razor templates have.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can update the question if the premise of the question is not clear.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're actually asking - there doesn't seem to be a question in your question?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I have explicitly added a question section. Hope it makes things clear.

Comment: Does the rendering code use subscriptions to watch for changes on the model etc?  I have a project with a bunch of stuff that gets rendered on a canvas based on the data in the view model - in that case it's just a case of loading the data back in

Comment: Yes, i have model binding using knockout. I am a serverside guy venturing into the world of front end. A simple example would be cool. Thanks!

Comment: I'll see what I can do - though it's pretty broad for stackoverflow.  May be tomorrow if I get a chance...

Comment: If i could describe the exact problem, I maybe putting my job in danger :). Sorry about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73727/discussion-between-perpetualcoder-and-james-thorpe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for dynamic templates, see [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) (Note 5)
In order to re-render UI you just need to update your observable with template binding.

```
<div data-bind='template: { name: shape }' />
```

And your javascript code

```
function RectangleViewModel(name, shape) {   
   this.name = ko.observable(name);
   this.shape = ko.observable(shape);

   this.changeShape = function () {       
       this.shape(this.shape.peek() === "circle" ? "rectangle" : "circle");
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new RectangleViewModel("Name", "rectangle"));
```

See [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/u9r8m0s0/)

Comment: In my case, there may be more than one kind of template. If that makes sense. Appreciate it.

Comment: In the sample there are 2 kind of templates  - circle and rectangle. You could add as many templates as you want. Just setting template name to the `shape` observable would update UI.